# How to use Cleave js/Vue-Cleave as a directive to input element in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use `vue-cleave` to format the input in my Vuejs application. However, I define it as a component and use the `cleave` tag to take advantage of the Vue-Cleave package. Here is the usage example:

```
<template>
  <cleave v-model="phoneNum" placeholder="Enter your phone number" :options="options"></cleave>
</template>

<script>
import Cleave from 'vue-cleave';
import CleavePhone from 'cleave.js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.i18n';

export default {
  data: function(){
    return {
      phoneNum:'',
      options: {
        phone: true,
        phoneRegionCode: 'US',
        delimiter: '-',
      }
    }
  components: {
    Cleave
  }
}
</script>
```

Now this works fine, but my requirement is to use it as a directive inside the `input` element. The code in the template would change to:

```
<input cleave="options" v-model="phoneNum" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
```

All, I know that this can be done in Angularjs as suggested by the document here: https://github.com/nosir/cleave.js/blob/master/doc/angularjs-directive-usage.md

How do I implement it in Vuejs? Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with `new Cleave()` that's in the docs?

Comment: @destoryer, I'm not sure Cleave can be used directly in the Vue App. That's why I'm using Vue-Cleave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I solved this problem:

Template:

```
<b-input type="tel" name="phone" ref="kPhone" v-model="phoneNumber" icon="phone"></b-input>
```

Script:

```
mounted() {
let element = this.$refs.kPhone.$el.querySelector('input');
new Cleave(element, {
  phone: true,
  phoneRegionCode: "US",
  delimiter: "-"
});
}
```

Comment: I believe that `cleave` attribute is unnecessary.

Comment: @destoryer, you are right! Thank you for correcting!